# Reactive updates not received in other browsertabs

Tags: meteor

Meteor promises *reactive updates*, so that views are auto-updated when data changes. The included *leaderboard* example demonstrates this. It runs fine when I test it: data is updated across several browsertabs in different browsers, as expected.

All set and go, I started coding with meteor and progress was being made, but when I tested for reactive updates across browertabs, I noticed that only **after a short while** the updates across tabs stopped.

I boiled down the problem to the following code, based on a new empty meteor project:

**updatebug.html**

```
<head>
  <title>updatebug</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> form}}
</body>

<template name="form">
  <form onsubmit="return false;">
  {{#each items}}
    {{> form_item }}
  {{/each}}
  </form>
</template>

<template name="form_item">
  <div>
    <label>{{name}}
      <input type="text" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}">
    </label>
  </div>
</template>
```

**updatebug.js:**

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection("items");

if (Meteor.is_client) {
  Template.form.items = function () {
    return Items.find();
  };

  Template.form_item.events = {
    'blur input': function(e) {
      var newValue = $(e.target).val();
      console.log('update', this.name, this.value, newValue);
      Items.update({_id: this._id}, {$set: {value: newValue}});
    },
  };
}

if (Meteor.is_server) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Items.find().count() === 0) {
      Items.insert({name: 'item1', value: 'something'});
    }
  });
}
```

Run in multiple browsertabs, start changing the value of the input in one tab. The other tabs will reflect the change. Goto the next tab and change the value. Repeat a couple of times.

After a while, no more updates are received by any other tabs. It seems that *once a tab has changed the value, it does not receive/show any more updates*.

Differences compared to the leaderboard example (since it's very similar):

- The leaderboard uses no form controls
- The leaderboard example does an increment operation on update, not a set

I am about to file a bug report, but want to be sure I am not doing anything stupid here, or missing an essential part of the Meteor Collection mechanics (yes, autopublish package is installed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is input element preservation.  Meteor will preserve the input state of any form field with an `id` or `name` attribute across a template redraw.  The redraw is preserving the old text in your form element, because you wouldn't want to interrupt another user typing in the same field.  If you remove the `name` attribute from the text box, each tab will update on blur.

In fact, I'm not sure why the first update works in your example.  That may actually be the bug!

You can see it's not a data problem by opening the console in each browser.  On each blur event you will get an updated document in every open tab.  (Type `Items.find().fetch()`)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I missed the relevant part in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#livehtml) about element preservation.